# undefined reference to method that's already defined

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an SDL window in C++. I have a Texture class which includes a constructor and a function for rendering which goes inside the main game loop. However, when I call this function the compiler says that it's an undefined referenced, despite the header being included inside of Game.cpp. Thank you.

**Game.h**

```cpp
class Game
{
private:
    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 360;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800;
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

public:
    bool Init();
    Game(/* args */);
    ~Game();
};
```

**Game.cpp**

```cpp
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Game.h"
#include "Texture.h"

Texture* testTexture;

bool Game::Init(){
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 ) {
        cerr << "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n" << SDL_GetError();
    }
    else {
        
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL ){
            SDL_Log("Could not create a Window: %s", SDL_GetError());
            return false;
        }

        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
        if ( renderer == NULL )
        {
            SDL_Log("Could not create a renderer: %s", SDL_GetError());
            return false;
        }

        testTexture = new Texture(renderer);
    }

    return true;
}

Game::Game(){
    if(Init()){
        while (true)
        {
            // Get the next event
            SDL_Event event;
            if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                // Break out of the loop on quit
                break;
                }
            }

            Uint8 red = rand() % 255;
            Uint8 green = rand() % 255;
            Uint8 blue = rand() % 255;

            // Fill the screen with the colour
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
            testTexture->Render();
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
    }
}

Game::~Game(){
    SDL_DestroyRenderer( renderer );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] ){
    Game* game = new Game();
}
```

**Texture.h**

```cpp
class Texture
{
private:
    SDL_Rect dest = { 0, 0, 100, 100 };
    SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
public:
    Texture(SDL_Renderer* renderer);
    ~Texture();
    void Render();
};
```

**Texture.cpp**

```cpp
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Texture.h"

void Texture::Render(){
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, texture, NULL, &dest, 0, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
}

Texture::Texture(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    this->renderer = renderer;
    // Load bitmap into surface
    SDL_Surface* buffer = SDL_LoadBMP("test.bmp");
    if ( !buffer ) {
        cout << "Error loading image test.bmp: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    }

    // Create texture
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, buffer );
    // Free surface as it's no longer needed
    SDL_FreeSurface( buffer );
    buffer = NULL;
    if ( !texture ) {
        cout << "Error creating texture: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    }

    buffer = SDL_LoadBMP("test.bmp");
    if ( !buffer ) {
        cout << "Error loading image test.bmp: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    }
}

Texture::~Texture()
{
}
```

I get the following error from g++:
`Game.cpp:58: undefined reference to Texture::Render()'`

Which is strange for me because as you can see, I have defined this function, so I am confused as to why I am being thrown this error. Thank you for your help

Comment: "undefined reference to.." means the definition is missing. If you fail to include a header, its a different error

Comment: There is no `Texture::Render` implementation in your cpp file

Comment: How are you **compiling** and **linking** your code?

Comment: If you are using VSCode and using code-runner or the built in c++ support this error is expected if you did not modify your build task. The VSCode documentation tells you it builds only the active file by default and tells you how to modify your tasks.json to have it build all source files in the workspace.

Comment: Ah that did it drescherjm thank you